# To show a function with a singularity is holomorphic by proving it is bounded.

Tags: complex-analysis

If $f\in H(A)$, where $A=\text{Ann($z_0;r_1,r_2$)}$.

Let $z\in \text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$, where $r_1<s_1<s_2<r_2$, define $g$ by

$$g(\zeta)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}  & \text{if }\zeta\neq z \\
\ f'(z) & \text{if }\zeta=z
\end{cases} $$
,where $\zeta \in \text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$.

I want to show that $g$ is bounded, so $z$ is a removable singularity of $\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}$ and $g$ is holomorphic on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$.

Since $f'(z)=l_0$ exists, $$ \forall \varepsilon>0 \;\;\exists \delta>0 \;\;\text{such taht  } \forall \zeta\in D(z,\delta), \;\;| \frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}|< \varepsilon+l_0$$

Can I use the definition of limit to show the boundedness of $g$? Or there is another way to show that.

Since $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$ is not compact, I think I can't say that $g$ is continuous and has maximum value.

Thanks for helping!!

Comment: Boundedness on the entire annulus is not required.

Comment: My version for Riemann removable singularity is that $f$ is holomorphic on $D^*(z_0,r)$ and is bounded, then $f$ has a holomorphic expansion on $D(z_0,r)$. Is that boundedness of $f$ isn't required for $D^*(z_0,r)$ ?

Comment: Boundeness in $D^{*}(z_0,r)$ is required **for some**  $r >0$. In this case you can take $r=\delta$ where $\delta$ is  the  number you got from definition of derivative. You can  take  $\epsilon =1$ in the argument.

Comment: If I take $r=\delta$ as you mentioned above, I consider that is $g$ bounded on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$ ?  Because the definition of derivative only shows that $g$ is bounded on an open disk $D(z,1+l_0)$ but not bounded on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)} $.

Comment: If I want to show that $g$ is bounded on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$, I think if I  can show that $g$ is bounded on $D(z,r)$ which contains the annulus then $g$ is bounded on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$. Am I correct?

Comment: Or, can I say that $g$ is continuous on $\{w \in \Bbb C \;|\; s_1 \le |w-z_0| \le s_2 \}$ which contains $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$ has maximum value $M$, so $g$ is bounded by $M$ on $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost answered it yourself. $|g(\zeta)| \leq (\epsilon+l_0) $ for $|\zeta -z| <\delta$. Boundedness in some disk around $z$ is enough to prove that the singularity is removable.

Comment: Can I say that there is a $\delta>0$ big enough so that $\forall \zeta \in D(z,\delta)$, $|g(\zeta)| \le \varepsilon + l_0$ for some big $\varepsilon > 0$  such that $g$ is bounded on $D(z,\varepsilon)$ which contain $\text{Ann($z_0;s_1,s_2$)}$ ?

Comment: In think you have read the statement of the theorem on removable singularities carefully. There is  absolutely no need to prove boundedness on the entire annulus.

Comment: Thanks, I have read my book, I think it is enough to show that a neighborhood of $z$ is bounded, then it has a holomorphic expansion on that neighborhood. In my case, $\frac{f(\zeta)-f(z)}{\zeta-z}$ has a holomorphic expansion $g$ on that neighborhood, and g is also holomorphic on the annulus outside the neighborhood, hence $g$ can be defined on the annulus.